# Post PHP code with HTML tags in Question

Tags: discussion

I am trying to post block of code like below

`$content = '<p>Header</p>';
 $content .= '<p><strong>sub-heading</strong></p>';`

If I post it in `<code>` tag, HTML tags are not showing,it just show content only..

How to I post above code in one block with HTML tags.?

It maybe not related to Magento, but I could't ask question in stack overflow, that the reason why I am asking here.

Comment: To post code blocks add 4 spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: beginning of the every line.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All lines of your code block have to start with 4 spaces.

Some more information here: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you @sv3n

Answer (score 1):

add the code in pre tag ie `<pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Sometime takes too long if your having to space each line.

I often use [this free handy tool](http://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowindentfourspaces/) that formats your code ready for stack overflow

Comment: Pro tip: start without the spaces, then select the code and press Ctrl-K to add indentation